# Using CORB with Marklogic 8

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-corb

Am a newbie to CORB and trying my hands on with the guide :

https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/Hello-World-from-CORB

My CORB JAR file version is :

> marklogic-corb-2.4.1

My MarkLogic xcc JAR file version is :

> marklogic-xcc-6.0.2

My MarkLogic version is :

> 8.0-5.5

I replicated the environment on my local system and while executing the script which contains the code as specified in the documentation guide :

```
THREAD-COUNT=8
URIS-MODULE=selector.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=transform.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=HelloWorldReport.csv
PRE-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PreBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-TOP-CONTENT=Title,Author,URI
```

The Script.sh contains the following code :

```
LIB=D:/POC

java -cp "$LIB/marklogic-xcc-6.0.2.jar;$LIB/marklogic-corb-2.4.1.jar" \
     -DOPTIONS-FILE=my.properties \
     com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager \
     xcc://admin:admin@localhost:8061/test
```

where `test is the database name and 8061 is the port number` of the database where the document is loaded

Note : Do we need to setup a XDBC Server separately... Assuming XDBC is not needed for Marklogic version 8

Am getting the following error :

```
SEVERE: Error initializing CORB ContentSource not available.
com.marklogic.developer.corb.CorbException: ContentSource not available.
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.DefaultContentSourcePool.get(DefaultContentSourcePool.java:117)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.prepareModules(Manager.java:680)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.init(Manager.java:174)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.AbstractManager.init(AbstractManager.java:168)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.main(Manager.java:129)
```

Answer (score 2):

That error is saying that it isn’t able to connect to the server. With an error like that I would check to see if you have the connect information correct. Then I would check to see if the computer you are running corb on can connect to the MarkLogic server. I’ve ran into issue where load balancer or firewalls block XCC connections.

I’d also update the XCC version you are using to the latest.

You don’t have to create an XCC app server but you do have to turn it on in the app server setting. When I run into issues with XCC to remove any issues that might be happening I create a separate XCC app server.

Comment: i am able to pass through the error when i am connecting to the new XDBC Server, i am getting the error

SEVERE: Error while running CORB
com.marklogic.developer.corb.CorbException: While invoking URIS-MODULE

URIS-MODULE=selector.xqy|ADHOC

Comment: Seems like there might be an error in the selector. I’d try running it in q console and make it works there. If that doesn’t work I’d create a new question and ask it there so that we can answer it there.

Comment: The contents of the selector.xqy is :

let $uris := "Hello"
return $uris

in QConsole it is returning "Hello" but the same error occurs when i try to run the shell script file.

The contents as mentioned in the blog post also reproduces the same error

Comment: I’m not sure if this is the issue but The collector is expecting a sequence with the first part being the count of Uris.

Comment: Vikaram, is it resolved now. I hope it should after Tyler's suggestion.